# SPLongOperation usage and SPDisposeCheck

Tags: splongoperation, spdisposechecker

I'm trying to use SPLongOperation like in the snippet below. When I run SPDisposeCheck, I get an error. So I have these questions:

1. Wouldn't the using statement call Dispose() on SPSite when execution is completed?
2. How can I give a friendly error message, regardless of the type of exception thrown during the long runnig process?

   ```
   protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // ..... removed for brevity

       SPLongOperation longOp = new SPLongOperation(this.Page);
       longOp.Begin();

       try     //getting error: Disposable type not disposed: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite
       {
           using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
           {
               using(SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb(client))
               {

                   // do long running process
                   // throw new Exception("Something went wonky!");

               }
           }

           longOp.End(redirectUrl);
       }
       catch (ThreadAbortException)
       {

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(ex.ToString());
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: You should do using(SPLongOperation longOp = new SPLongOperation(this.Page)) {...} to get rid of Disposable type not disposed error.

Comment: Yes. Moving the SPLongOperation inside the try block and using a 'using' statement worked.